# Can we create separate SharePoint List View for each Security Group?

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, list-view, modern-experience, communication-site

I have the SharePoint List where a few SharePoint Security Groups are having unique permissions.

Now, I want to create a separate view (personal view) for each of that security group, so that, the other group member can not see the view of the rest of the security groups.

How can I achieve the above behavior? Is it possible to set the permissions on List Views?

I am using the SharePoint Online Communication site (Modern Experience only).

Answer (score 1):

In SharePoint online modern experience, it is not possible to set the permissions on List Views.

Also, you cannot create personal (private) views for security groups in SharePoint lists.

Audience targeting on list views is not supported in modern experience yet.

---

Here are SharePoint UserVoice posts that you can vote for:

1. [Allow setting permissions for each view in the list/library](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/329214-sites-and-collaboration/suggestions/37251427-allow-setting-permissions-for-each-view-in-the-lis)
2. [target audience list view](https://sharepoint.uservoice.com/forums/330318-sharepoint-administration/suggestions/35509145-target-audience-list-view)

**Similar threads**:

1. [SharePoint Online list modern view](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/255745/spo-list-view-target-audience.html)
2. [Audience targeting SharePoint modern view](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/audience-targeting-sharepoint-modern-view/m-p/169397)

Answer (score 1):

You can't filter the list view based on user permissions/security groups. If user have read permissions on all items in list then they will be able to see all items.

Here is a similar case for your reference:

- [modern list view Filter list view based on membership in SharePoint group](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sharepoint/sharepoint-list-view-depending-on-user-group/m-p/2077064)